# How to say "post" as in "post something online"?

Tags: translation

I can't find a dictionary translation of the word "post". For example,

> Did you see what I *posted* on Facebook?

or

> Have you seen my *post* on my Moments (Wechat)?

**Update:**

What do they say in northern China? (Colloquially)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Colloquially people use 'PO' (mostly in Southern China), 发, 贴, 放, or any verb that has a similar meaning.

Formal translation would be 发布 or 发表.

> Did you see what I posted on Facebook? 你看见我在Facebook上**PO**的东西了吗？
>
> Where did you post it? On WeChat Moments. 你**发**在哪了？微信朋友圈。

Comment: What about in northern China?

Comment: @tofu_bacon In Northern China 'PO' is rarely used, the other words are common.

Answer (score 2):

Post mean a lot of things in this certain context. So we use many words.

- When use as a verb, it means 发/贴
- When use as a noun, it means 帖子/评论/留言/状态 *Name changes with certain platfrom*

Answer (score 1):

Did you see what I posted on your Facebook? = 你看到我在你的QQ空间上的留言了吗？

Did you see what I posted on Facebook? = 你看到我在QQ空间上发表的说说了吗？

Comment: QQ空間 certainly isn't Facebook. You can say 臉書, right?

Comment: Facebook is banned in China, qq is not, so I thought I'd use qq, same difference as far as 'post' is concerned. Those sentences were taken from my phone, sent to me by friends.

Answer (score 1):

- Did you see what I posted on Facebook? In this context, Post is verb.
  which means 发布，发表，公布
- Have you seen my post on my Moments (Wechat)? In this context, Post is noun.

  1. on Wechat, it means 朋友圈，圈文
  2. on Weibo, it means，微博，状态
  3. on Blog, it means 文章
  4. on Community/forum, it means 帖子，评论，留言 等等。